# Access Chrome Window Context from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, process

I want to be able to access the current running chrome window and get the number of opened tabs using NodeJS.

Comment: What you're asking about is not possible, at least without writing Chrome extension. You likely have XY problem. Consider reasking the question with your real problem explained, in case there's any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This completely seems impossible the reason is given below.

- Node.js is server-side languages you can not access DOM
  (client-side information) from the server until you pass something to the server.
- You can find in which browser user is using but not how many tabs
  currently, the user is currently opened.
- It might be possible by client-side js library eg. jquery.

Comment: I see a website implement a feature that detected if the user opened a new tab or left the page. Any hints about how to implement something like this ?